# How can I restrict a result to only include rows where one specific field is unique with UNION Select statement in BigQuery?

Tags: select, google-bigquery, union, where-clause

I have the following code. I try to stitch the two tables together, but restrict it to only add duplicate Opportunity_ID once, and then from the second table (OpportunitiesUpdates).

```
SELECT
  Opportunity.Account_Name,
  Opportunity.Opportunity_Name,
  Opportunity.Opportunity_Owner,
  Opportunity.Opportunity_ID
FROM
  Opportunity
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
  OpportunityUpdates.Account_Name,
  OpportunityUpdates.Opportunity_Name,
  OpportunityUpdates.Opportunity_Owner,
  OpportunityUpdates.Opportunity_ID
FROM
  OpportunityUpdates
WHERE OpportunityUpdates.Opportunity_ID <> Opportunity.Opportunity_ID
```

Comment: not clear what exactly logic to apply - provide some sample data and expected output to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

This code consolidates all records from both tables (by `Opportunity_ID`) and gives priority to the `OpportunityUpdates` table based on `Opportunity_ID`.

It assumes that the same `Opportunity_ID` could be in either table ("duplicates"), but that *within* each table an `Opportunity_ID` is unique.  It also assumes that `Opportunity_ID` is not nullable (never null).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  IF(ou.Opportunity_ID IS NOT NULL, ou.Account_Name, o.Account_Name) Account_Name,
  IF(ou.Opportunity_ID IS NOT NULL, ou.Opportunity_Name, o.Opportunity_Name) Opportunity_Name,
  IF(ou.Opportunity_ID IS NOT NULL, ou.Opportunity_Owner, o.Opportunity_Owner) Opportunity_Owner,
  COALESCE(ou.Opportunity_ID, o.Opportunity_ID) Opportunity_ID
FROM OpportunityUpdates ou
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Opportunity o
  ON o.Opportunity_ID = ou.Opportunity_ID
```